# How accurate is Stack Exchange's idea of time?

Tags: support, winter-bash, time, winter-bash-2017

Currently there is an incentive to post a question in a specific minute of the hour (the first, for the record).  In order to do, I posted, [Any GPIO library that supports I2C multi-master mode?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76780/36970) which was around 15 seconds past the top of the hour (which was 7pm in New York) according to my `nptd` synchronised PC.  After waiting patiently for a day my reaction to the gamification on SE had still not earned it's reward - and I'm as *Mad as a Hatter* (and not a "Hero of Time") but not so Mad I cannot wait until 7pm in Tokyo...

Question: just how accurate is the Stack Exchange time-keeping?

Comment: Yeah - it was the lack of an upvote - as mentioned in the first question suggested as a duplicate - don't you just _love_ hidden rules...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite accurate, and the 'window' is one minute. The timezone of your PC doesn't matter; it needs to be 7:00:00pm - 7:00:59pm *anywhere* in the world.

Your problem is that the Hero of Time hat, like most Winter Bash hats, has an additional hidden requirement: your question must have a *positive* score. It didn't have it at the moment you posted this Meta question; it does have now, so your Hero of Time hat should be on its way.